# Displaying associated product's image on configurable product in magento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento

I have used [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/change_product_image_on_view_page_to_associated_product_s_image) to achieve this. but when I change the option I'm having this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null configurable.js:159
Product.Config.configureElement configurable.js:159
Product.Config.configure configurable.js:127
(anonymous function) prototype.js:391
_createResponder.responder prototype.js:5598
```

is there anyone can help me with this?
Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

or could you advise me any other solution to make this happen? thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that most of your product have images associated to them and your image have an id

```
  <img id="image" .. />
```

Using chrome debugging tool or firebug for firefox try

```
console.log(assocIMG); // should return all products image url
console.log(assocIMG[productNo]);  // should return image url
```

(around line $('image').src = assocIMG[productNo];)

Comment: Hi R.S **console.log(assocIMG[productNo]);** this gives correct image path from the console but why dose not work on the screen? what do you thin? thanks

Comment: Does your img tag have an id='image' e.g `<img id="image" ..`?

Comment: I have added id="image" and now pictures changes. thank for your help but how can I change the <a href="" ? because when you click image popup comes up and expands the image. but the popup image is still old image. <a href="images/img.jpg"><img src="images/img.jpg" /></a> how can i change the a href? thank you.

Comment: You could either (1) give the `a tag` a class name/id e.g `<a href='..' id='image_href'` then `$('image_href').href=assocIMG[productNo];` or (2) `$('image').previous('a').href = assocIMG[productNo];'

Comment: fantastic. I thank you so much sir. thanks for your help and I hope I'm going learn this javascript as well as you. thank you!! I gave my a tag id="image_href" and used .href() everyhing is working. thanks so much. I can't vote you i don't have enough points:(